# Taylor Series approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

> Let $f(x) = (1-x)^{-1}$ and $x_0=0$. Find the $n$-th Taylor polynomial $P_n(x)$ for $f(x)$ about $x_0$. Find a value of $n$ necessary to approximate $f(x)$ within $10^{-6}$ on $[0,0.5]$.

I am having problem in this question. Can someone get me started with this question?

Comment: sorry about that. Question has been updated now.

Comment: It would be nicer of you to re-type the question in a readable and searchable format, using tips from [the notation help page](/help/notation) to get mathematical expressions right. I've done this for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the Taylor polynomial says:

$$ P_n(x) = P_0(x) + \cdots + P_{n-1}(x) + \frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^n$$

you will easily find yours to be of the form:

$$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+ \cdots$$.

Then find $k$ such that $$0.5^k + 0.5^{k+1} \cdots < 10^{-6}$$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: For $|x| < 1$ you have that
$$(1+x)^\alpha = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty x^k \binom{\alpha}{k}$$

Note that you can extend the binomial coefficient to make it work with any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.
Now it is easier to see that
$$\begin{align*}
(1+x)^{-1} &= 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4 - x^5 + o(x^5)\\
(1-x)^{-1} &= 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + o(x^5)
\end{align*}$$

Can you continue from here?